# keeping answers in a variable with jquery - why doesn't this work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so i have a survey that displays one question at a time. when the user clicks his/her answer, the question fades away and the next question fades in. at the end of the survey i want to display all the answers they selected.

so here is my function that runs when the user selects an option:

```
    $('#actualThumbnails .thumb').click(function(){
    var id = this.id;
    var myClass = $(this).attr('class');
    firstQuestion = myClass+id;
    allAnswers += firstQuestion;
    startQuestionTwo();
});
```

So ideally at the end, i'd have to print allAnswers and it should work. But for some reason allAnswers isn't getting the variable. This actually breaks the thing from working, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: Is `allAnswers` declared as a `global variable`? Can you please add more JS code.

Comment: can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: i feel like an idiot but i actually forgot to declare `allAnswers` as global. For some reason I thought not using `var` would declare it as global, but that's wrong. thanks, i figured it out

Comment: not using var does make it global, but you have to still initialize it to something.  Also, not using var to specifically make it global is considered bad practice, the preferred method it to declare it in the global scope first to make it obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you declare `allAnswers` outside of the function in a global scope

```
var allAnswers;
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to say is, try console.log(...), this allows you to write objects and information to your browsers javascript-console (firebug in ff, CTRL+SHIFT+I in chrome and F12 in ie) debug your application using this, as it can be one of many reasons.

Anyhow, You did not declare allAnswers, maybe try something like this:

```
var allAnswers = new Array();

$('#actualThumbnails .thumb').click(function(){
    var id = this.id;
    var myClass = $(this).attr('class');
    firstQuestion = myClass+id;
    allAnswers.push("This should be the answer for question " + id);
    startQuestionTwo();
});
```

Comment: You can also press `F12` in Chrome ;)